# Fetch the next strategy based on the old strategies in MySQL

Tags: mysql, arrays, random, numbers, find-occurrences

I have the following problem:

- I have a table with 4 thousand records with the following columns, id, strategy, option and data.
- The numbers are random, line by line.
- I needed to check if the previous 3 records are part of my pattern and search for the next 2 numbers, line by line.

#### Example

My previous strategies for the search are:

```text
strategy: 4
strategy: 2
strategy: 9
current: 14
```

Now I need to look for the next strategy, which in this case would be 11, so I needed to consult the last 4 strategies and check if they match the ones I'm looking for.

I would need to fetch 4,2,9,14 and find 11, and it would have to be in ID order.

Below is an example print of my table:
[image: an example print of my table.]

Comment: I'm failing to see why this is tagged `random`. Your strategy column is tabled, not random. Where did the prior strategies come from, and what's the basis for picking 11 as the next one vs 5 or 6?

Comment: These strategies are updated by the marketing team, the numbers range from 1 to 14 of strategy.

The strategy column is random, but each number in it has an exact option.

But I need to predict when the next strategy will be based on the old sequence of numbers.

Comment: For example, the marketing team launched the following strategies:

14 facebook
12 facebook
0 google

I need to predict, based on the previous 3 records which will be the next one, based on the pattern.

There are only 3 strategy options:

Facebook
linkedin
Google

However, the strategy number refers to an option in the CRM.

This strategy number refers to the investment you will make.

For example, I will make a 4 strategy investment in linkedin option.

Did you understand? @pjs